# query to get child object data

Tags: query, master-detail

I'm pretty new to SalesForce and my question should be very simple.

I'm creating an extension for a standard controller of a custom object called Bill_Account_*c. This object has a master detail field with another custom object called Bill*_c.

In the constructor, I want to get the Bill__c associated to the Bill_Account__c.

Here's what I've tried in apex:

```
public newConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
    controller = standardController;
    billAccount = (Bill_Account__c)controller.getRecord();

Bill__c bill = [SELECT Id, Bill_Field1__c, Bill_Field2__c FROM Bill__c WHERE Id = :billAccount.Bill__c];

}
```

but I get this error:

```
SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Bill_Account__c.Bill__c
```

What am I doing wrong? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: There are no silly questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to re-query the record, so instead of what you have you would need to do this:

```
public newConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
    controller = standardController;
    billAccount = (Bill_Account__c)controller.getRecord();

    billAccount = [ Select Bill__c Where Id = billAccount.Id ];

Bill__c bill = [SELECT Id, Bill_Field1__c, Bill_Field2__c FROM Bill__c WHERE Id = :billAccount.Bill__c];

}
```

I think if Bill__c is not used in your VF page, you have to physically re-query it. The other solution would be to make it a hidden field in your VF page if it doesn't need to be displayed.

**EDIT** - or, as Mike points out an even better solution seems to be to use `controller.addFields(List<String> fieldNames)` thus saving yourself a SOQL query

Comment: Or use `controller.addFields(List<string> fieldNames)` - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm

Comment: So when you do that, you don't need to re-query and getRecord() does the magic? Seems a better solution

Comment: Correct; you call addFields before getting the record and it adds those fields to the record.

Comment: Cool, if you want to post an answer I'll delete this one as thats a better approach, and thanks for the tip - learnt something new today!

Comment: Eh, just add that option to your answer.

Comment: Ok, cheers @MikeChale

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a problem with addFields not working in test context. As a result I favoured using the hidden field on the VF page. This describes it https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008ytQIAQ

Comment: Good to know @DougB...I generally go with the hidden field, can sometimes be a ballache though if your controller is called from multiple VFs and email templates and you remember after the event :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix:  Since you are using a Standard Controller, you need to either include that field on the VF page somewhere (so the `StandardController` does the querying), or you need to query it yourself.

try this:

```
public newConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
    id billAccountId = standardController.getId();
    billAccount = [SELECT id,Bill__c
                   FROM Bill_Account__c
                   WHERE id=:billAccountId];

    Bill__c bill = [SELECT Id, Bill_Field1__c, Bill_Field2__c, Bill_Account__c.Bill__c 
                    FROM Bill__c 
                    WHERE Id = :billAccount.Bill__c];

}//END init(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
```

Comment: Or use `controller.addFields(List<string> fieldNames)` - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm